# Vinyl Siding Holes

Tags: roofing, vinyl-siding

[image]What would the reason be for holes or snips in multiple places on vinyl siding but all in the same relative location just at different parts of the roof, with all at the ends of a bottom panel of siding just above the ends of J-channels that are just above the roof-wall intersection? In other words, this has nothing to do with the age or condition of the siding, as all snips or holes would not be in the same place.
Update Edit: I've been asked for a picture which I attached. Apparently the described location of snipped siding is confusing. I cannot go up to my roof to show another location, and in the exact location of the picture the snip/slice was sealed with white caulk to match white siding, so you cannot see in the photo it was snipped. You will see where the eave edge of a roof meets a sidewall, and J-channel ends on the lower panel of sidewall just above a roof-wall intersection before the sidewall continues past the gutter and eave edge of the roof. Just above the end of that J-channel was a snip or slice, and this is in multiple locations.

Updated: Added picture showing where J-channel is in siding just above roof-wall interface, where there was a non-sealed snip/slice in the siding just about where the J-channel - and I was told in multiple locations - but this location - the only one I can get close enough for a half-way decent picture was sealed with white caulk on white siding so in this picture you cannot see that it had been snipped/sliced. This does show though the type of locations on my roof.

Comment: Photo would help.

Comment: I'm in the middle of installing vinyl siding on my house and your textual description of the issue has me lost. _mumblemumble a picture is worth 1000 words mumblemumble..._

Comment: If the siding was from a different house, would say those snips/holes were made so the siding could fit up the roof rafters.  Do not know why siding would be snipped unless to fit over something, which sounds like is not needed on your house.  As the other two comments stated, pictures will help so we can see also.

Comment: I added photo and read "update" in original post please.

Comment: Re-roofed years ago. Someone said siding is commonly snipped in these locations to lift up the bottom panel to view/gain access to step flashing or open space to work at roof-wall interface if they don't want to remove panel......This could've been done to decide if flashing would be replaced, or to reposition &/or replace 1, 2, more or all pieces of flashing, but I was told my flashing was not replaced (warped, numerous, unsealed empty nail holes), and it appears old flashing was removed and old flashing was reinstalled, and I think these snips in siding are giving that illusion.

Comment: Just because it's snipped, doesn't mean roofer removed all flashing and reinstalled all flashing, or even any, as they could've wanted to view condition to decide if they'd replace it, or just to reposition/replace a 1 or 2 pieces, or to try to make 1 or 2 shingles overlap better with flashing as new ones are often a different size than old ones, and without removing to alternately instal shingles & flashing unless new shingles are exact same size, eventually there will be insufficient overlap, or misalignment which a roofer may or may not take the time and effort to correct.

Comment: I'm wondering if there're times the bottom siding panel is lifted up to replace old shingles even if the roofer doesn't intend to view or move any old flashing. I read sometimes a nail is to close to the intersection. Could that make it hard to remove the nail and old shingle without moving siding out of the way? Even if there is no intention to view/move any flashing, would just removing old nails, shingles and then weaving in new shingles into proper position relative to installed old flashing sometimes require lifting up/removing siding for better access?

Comment: Can you highlight what you're talking about in the picture?

Comment: Not sure how. To left of "J-channel" label, see grayed, dirty caulked siding where a snip was sealed so you can't even see it was snipped. The photo just shows location. My siding was snipped in multiple same-type locations in proximity of end of J-channel above the roof-wall intersection where gutter edge of the roof attaches to the sidewall where kickout flashing is often installed. I can't get on roof for better picture. My questions are about purpose of snips are in prior posts and comments.